I want to compute the CWM but unfortunately the same error appears: First argument not valid
I'm using two datasets imported on R using the command read.csv(). The first one (spxt) includes the traits of an insect community and the second one (spxpl) contains relative abundances of insects per plot (invaded or not). After cleaning the datasets from values NA which I converted to 0 and assuring that the datasets have the same number of row (which they have), I proceeded to compute the CWM which concluded with the error showed in the image: "First argument not valid".



I tried everything I believed possible:

I tried to convert the dataframe in matrix
I tried to convert the content of the "spxt" into factor
I tried to use the function na.omit without converting the NA in 0 before I realized it wasn't possible because the two dataframes have to have the same number of rows.
I tried anything that came to mind.


https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example
